# CSS. How to exclude a tag from doing something?

Tags: html, css

I made all my images move to the left a little bit whenever I hover over them. But I want to exclude the images that have certain ID or class set up by me. How do I do that?

My hover code:

```
a:hover
{
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.myclass:hover {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: With 0 values the unit isn't necessary, `margin-left: 0;` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `:not()` selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/:not

Comment: Although bear in mind that it's not supported by IE before version 9.

Comment: Thank you, that will come in handy.